# Can I use a Github OAuth app's generated access token for pushing code to a repository of the user?

Tags: github, oauth-2.0, github-api, github-oauth

I know there is a hacky way of modifying content of user's repo through the [GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents#create-or-update-file-contents) which just needs an access token and `workflow` scope. What I would like to do is use this access token in place of the [Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) and push code from CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It works by itself. Access token generated using Oauth apps can be used for pushing code to repo(provided the scope for the token includes `repo`).